# How to deploy whatsapp-web.js on google cloud run?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, whatsapp, google-cloud-run

I have a nodejs application that listens to events on the firebase firestore and performs actions on the **whatsapp-web.js** client based on the event.

The process is as follows:
Let's say I have a collection **"requests"** in firestore and every time a document in the collection is created (**updated**), it generates the following actions:

- The function in my nodejs code that **listens** for events will retrieve the document, read the request and **launch an action from the whatsapp-web.js client**.
- The whatspp-web.js client to perform the action, **must launch, initialize a connection, and then perform the request action** (the document from the request collection) **once the client is connected**.

*Except that cloud run closes before all these previous functions are performed.*

Is there a way to solve this problem with cloud run or should we look for an alternative solution like compute engine?